# How to assign / set specific php version to composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, wamp

I have multiple versions of php installed on my wamp . now I am running  PHP 7.0.15 as you can see in screenshot, but the laravel I am using is still taking 5.5.12 and I am unable t  use laravelcollective .

OS : Windows 10 Pro

How I can fix it ?

[image]

Updated information

```
E:\work\www\my-project>php --version
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2015 23:48:00)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

so, it seems my project is using  5.4.45 command line. may be I need to change it ? but having no idea of it.

Comment: @JewelFarazi up vote 1 down vote means ? I have neither upvoted anyone here neither downvoted .only reading suggestions.

Comment: sorry mistake @prafulla kumar sahu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED, I fixed it by changing the `%PATH%` environment variable to fix it . I added path of all php versions I have to `%PATH%`, as per my requirement I can arrange it from top to bottom, as CLI will take the first one it will get from Top to bottom in environment variable setting.

please check [this](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6113)
 to have a better idea about my solution.