# Composer reads php version wrong?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8

When I try to run composer update it gives me that error message

```
This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

and when I try composer dump-autoload on my laravel app  it gives me

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home2/elmohare/public_html/okttob/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 380
```

**NOTE :: the app works great on my localhost but I have this problem only on my server**

when I try `php -v` it gives me

```
PHP 7.3.5 (cli) (built: May  7 2019 16:13:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
```

and I searched about this problem, all people say that apache version is different of php cli version, but the real problem is I've made `phpinfo()` file on my server to see the apache php verison and it gave me also

```
PHP Version 7.3.5
```

So it seems right, anyone knows the solution?

Comment: If you have multiple PHP versions installed, it could be that Composer is looking at the wrong one to check the version. e.g. - maybe it's searching for the first binary which matches the pattern `/usr/bin/php*` but your PATH variable is actually running `/usr/local/bin/php`. Try running `locate bin/php` and see what comes up, then for each file returned that looks like a PHP binary, try running `-v` on it.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env php -v` will show you the version of PHP that composer is using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign / set specific php version to composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908492/how-to-assign-set-specific-php-version-to-composer)

Comment: Does your `composer.json` file possibly include (`platform`)[https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform] config, which would override the PHP version installed on the server with the one specified there?

Comment: my composer.json doesnot but my composer.lock has the platform to 7.1.3 witch is lower than 7.3.5 on my server >> should I edit it  to be 7.3.5 or delete it ??
** please note that my local host php version is 7.1.3 and my server is 7.5.3 so if I edit the platform it will not work on my localhost I think **

Comment: You could just try deleting the lock file and running composer install. (Backup first of course.)